# Why is my bash prompt repeating its last line twice, when I ls, or cd or issue misc commands?

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1

My prompt is such:

```
PS1="\[\033[32m\]\u@myserver\n\[\033[33m\w$\033[0m\] "
```

So as output after I **ls** i see this:

```
jake@myserver
~/public_html$
~/public_html$
```

When I should only (I think) see:

```
jake@myserver
~/public_html$
```

The color commands work (beautifully) but this duplicate line thing is driving me nuts.
I adapted this command prompt from the one that comes with MySysGit for windows.

Why is this happening?

If I just hit **enter** at the prompt, it prints correctly, without the duplicate second line.  The duplication only happens after **ls**, **cd** or maybe some other bash commands.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `\]` before the `\w` but I don't think that's related to the problem you're asking about...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the doubling, but you're missing two escaped brackets:

```
PS1="\[\033[32m\]\u@myserver\n\[\033[33m\]\w$\[\033[0m\] "
```

You might also see if `PROMPT_COMMAND` has a value. It may be producing some output. This will tell you what it's set to:

```
echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
```

Without knowing what it contains, I can't tell you what to do about it if it is part of the problem. However, you can clear it like this:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=
```

That's nothing after the equal sign.

Comment: After setting my prompt to what you gave me in the first sample the doubling goes away.  Weird, and thanks!